# Anychart - How do I make the scroller contain an image of the chart?

Tags: anychart

I saw a chart the other day that had a cool miniature image of itself inside of the scroller. I would love to know how to do something similar. The chart I am refereeing to can be found here: 
[Daily Nav](http://www.jllipt.com/daily-nav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using background series option of the scroller, as described at https://docs.anychart.com/7.14.3/Stock_Charts/Scroller#background_series

Basic sample is available at https://playground.anychart.com/docs/7.14.3/samples/STOCK_Scroller_03-plain

Any of the series available for stock charts https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.enums.StockSeriesType
can be displayed in the scroller.

Comment: Thank you! How can I change the color of the series inside the scroller?
I am trying to use series.fill("color") for an area chart inside the scroller but it still shows up as the default color.

Comment: With scroller or any other series you have fill and selectFill, and when the range is shown it shows selectFill, so you have changed the basic fill but it is covered. See the sample to get the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/0b24d4dd/1/